MetaQuest3のマルチユーザー対応アプリでPUN2を使用して空間アンカーを共有する方法がわからない
現在、MetaQuest3用のマルチユーザーのパススルー機能を使用したアプリケーションの開発に取り組んでいます。以下の参考記事を基に、空間アンカーの配置には成功しました。
参考記事: Quest Spatial Anchor - Zenn
しかし、次のステップとしてPhoton Unity Networking 2（PUN2）を用いてアプリをマルチユーザー対応にしたいと考えています。具体的には、配置した空間アンカーを複数のユーザー間で共有・同期させたいのですが、実装方法がよくわかりません。
現在の状況:

空間アンカーの配置はローカル環境で正常に動作しています。
PUN2の基本的なセットアップは完了していますが、アンカーの共有方法が不明です。

質問:
マルチユーザー環境で空間アンカーを共有・同期させるために、PUN2をどのように実装すれば良いでしょうか？具体的なコード例やベストプラクティスがあれば教えていただけると助かります。
補足情報:

使用しているUnityのバージョン: 2022.3
PUN2のバージョン: 最新版
空間アンカー関連のプラグインやMeta XR All-in-one SDKを使用

よろしくお願いいたします。
